# UML sequence diagram with idle interval

Tags: uml

How could I represent the following in a sequence diagram:

1. A :Browser finds a device on the network and notifies its delegate
2. The :Delegate queues the device
3. When the :Delegate finally decides it should connect, it asks the :Browser to do so

My difficulty is in representing the transition between steps 2 and 3. The devices are being queue so that connections happen one at a time. Which symbol do I use to represent this "waiting" period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you do not note any delay. If you're actively waiting in some delay loop you can call an internal method `delay(time)`. But in your case the delay is ended upon request. That is when the message from the `:Delegate` arrives. It is possible to add time constraints between messages:

[image]

For details see *Figure 17.5 Sequence Diagram with time and timing* on p. 569 of Superstructures formal-15-03-01 (latest UML 2.5 spec)

Comment: What if it's not a timed delay? I mean, in this case, as the device is queued it will connect when all other devices in front of it have connected

Comment: The condition is probably the result of some operation. You need to show that operation. Eventually use a self-call to show that it will do something before connecting.

Comment: Did that, looks great! Thanks.